# Sound card not detected except in recovery mode (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)

Tags: sound, kernel, pulseaudio

For a few days, my sound card is not detected anymore: only “dummy output” (and no input at all) is proposed in the sound parameter window! I tried many forum solutions, in particular I un-installed and re-installed the audio drivers many times; but that did not change anything… :-(

However, when booting via recovery mode, audio works fine. (And audio works fine too when booting with Windows). So I guess this is somehow a kernel issue… Nevertheless, trying to boot with either of two previous (non-recovery) versions of the kernel did not work either! (Currently my kernel is 5.4.0-62-generic; so the two previous kernels were 5.4.0-60-generic and 5.4.0-58-generic).

Any ideas on what could have caused that problem, and how to solve it…? Tell me if you need some more info about my laptop configuration :-)

**Edit —** When logging in normal mode, kern.log reads (I searched all the lines for “audio”, “sound”, “realtek”, “speaker” and “phone”):

```
kernel: [    0.178283] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
kernel: [    3.416730] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
kernel: [    3.502366] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC3246: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
kernel: [    3.502369] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
kernel: [    3.502370] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
kernel: [    3.502372] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
kernel: [    3.502373] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
kernel: [    3.502374] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headset Mic=0x19
kernel: [    3.502376] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headphone Mic=0x1a
kernel: [    3.502377] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
kernel: [    3.557818] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
kernel: [    3.557858] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
kernel: [    3.557893] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
kernel: [    3.557925] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
kernel: [    3.557995] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
kernel: [    3.558075] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
```

When booting in recovery mode, it reads the following. **Note that time ~64 s is most probably the first time at which I tried to launch (successfully) some sound for testing**:

```
kernel: [    0.176116] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
kernel: [   64.803641] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: couldn't bind with audio component
kernel: [   64.860025] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC3246: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
kernel: [   64.860027] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
kernel: [   64.860028] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
kernel: [   64.860028] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
kernel: [   64.860029] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
kernel: [   64.860030] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headset Mic=0x19
kernel: [   64.860031] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headphone Mic=0x1a
kernel: [   64.860032] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
kernel: [   64.909672] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
kernel: [   64.910739] hdaudio hdaudioC0D2: Unable to bind the codec
kernel: [   64.911932] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
```

So it seems that, paradoxically, it is when the codec *succeeds* to be bound that things go badly…!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.04.1 LTS (edited post accordingly)

Comment: Compare the /var/log files between the working case(friendly-recovery mode) and failing case(normal boot) to search for clues.

Comment: @mao Any clues about which of these files I should look at ?… Here are the contents of the directory :
`alternatives.log
alternatives.log.1
alternatives.log.10.gz
alternatives.log.11.gz
alternatives.log.12.gz
alternatives.log.2.gz
alternatives.log.3.gz
alternatives.log.4.gz
alternatives.log.5.gz
alternatives.log.6.gz
alternatives.log.7.gz
alternatives.log.8.gz
alternatives.log.9.gz
apport.log
apport.log.1
apport.log.2.gz
apport.log.3.gz
apport.log.4.gz
apport.log.5.gz
apport.log.6.gz
apport.log.7.gz
apt
auth.log
auth.log.1
auth.log.2.gz
auth.log.3.gz
auth.log.4.gz
`

Comment: `boot.log
boot.log.1
boot.log.2
boot.log.3
boot.log.4
boot.log.5
bootstrap.log
btmp
btmp.1
cups
dist-upgrade
dmesg
dmesg.0
dmesg.1.gz
dmesg.2.gz
dmesg.3.gz
dmesg.4.gz
dpkg.log
dpkg.log.1
dpkg.log.10.gz
dpkg.log.11.gz
dpkg.log.12.gz
dpkg.log.2.gz
dpkg.log.3.gz
dpkg.log.4.gz
dpkg.log.5.gz
dpkg.log.6.gz
dpkg.log.7.gz
dpkg.log.8.gz
dpkg.log.9.gz
faillog
firebird
fontconfig.log
fsck
gdm3
gpu-manager.log
installer
journal
kern.log
kern.log.1
kern.log.2.gz
kern.log.3.gz
kern.log.4.gz
lastlog
lightdm
openvpn
private
speech-dispatcher
`

Comment: `syslog
syslog.1
syslog.2.gz
syslog.3.gz
syslog.4.gz
syslog.5.gz
syslog.6.gz
syslog.7.gz
tallylog
ubuntu-advantage.log
unattended-upgrades
upgrade
wtmp
wtmp.1
Xorg.0.log
Xorg.0.log.old
Xorg.1.log
Xorg.1.log.old
`

Comment: use grep -il to find files that mention your sound card driver, and/or your sound card. As you gave zero facts in your question I cannot guess what it is, but kern.log* can be helpful. Also, look at the *timestamps* on the files, only a few of them will be appended/written by booting. Study them.

Comment: @mao I edited the wanted information :-) Sorry for my not giving relevant information sooner: I am far from an expert; and moreover this is my very first question on Ask Ubuntu… :-|

Comment: My Intel HD audio built in motherboard sound is no longer detected after upgrading recently.  Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: @OwN Sadly not… :-(

Comment: @OwN Do not ask me why, but today as of Jan. 28, 2021, sound works again on my laptop! (in non-recovery mode, I mean). Maybe the cause could be that my last-but-one boot was under Windows, and that Windows performed some update before leaving…!?—By the way, it is also possible that the last-but-one boot just BEFORE the problem occurred was also a Window boot.